# Can __thread can be used for a local variable

Tags: c

I have a function like this that uses static variable. Now i need to use it in a multi threaded application.

```
char *
ether_ntoa(const struct ether_addr *n)
{
    static char a[18];
    return (ether_ntoa_r(n, a));
}
```

Can i use the __thread variable instead?

```
char *
ether_ntoa(const struct ether_addr *n)
{
   __thread char a[18];
   return (ether_ntoa_r(n, a));
}
```

I realize  i can add another argument to ether_ntoa function, but was wondering whether this will work as well?

Comment: Neither of those is thread-safe.  The return value of the second variant points to the thread-local storage of the thread that made the call, but there is no guarantee that the pointer won't be passed to another thread.

Comment: True. But i just needed it for a debug output. So it works for me. But as you pointed out the return value can't be used after a subsequent call to the same function. Sending it to another thread per se wil work.  =When the address-of operator is applied to a thread-local variable, it is evaluated at run-time and returns the address of the current thread's instance of that variable. An address so obtained may be used by any thread. = quote from gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will work, but keep the `static` specifier.  From the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Thread-Local.html):

> The __thread specifier may be used alone, with the extern or static
>   specifiers, but with no other storage class specifier. When used with
>   extern or static, __thread must appear immediately after the other
>   storage class specifier.
>
> The __thread specifier may be applied to any global, file-scoped
>   static, function-scoped static, or static data member of a class. It
>   may not be applied to block-scoped automatic or non-static data
>   member.